# mongoose and express - how to combine two functions into one output

Tags: node.js, mongoose, express

i'm trying to make search form for my site, with two separate inputs, one for title keywords and the other one for body of the post. I don't know how to pass these 2 variables (asd for title and asdd for body) to function, thats my app.js file :

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    postdb.findByTitle(asd, function(error, article) {
        res.render('search.jade',
        { locals: {
            title: article.title,
            articles:article
        }
        });
    });
});
```

and here is function for finding (check the bold parts):

```
PostDB.prototype.findByTitle = function(**asd asdd**, callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, article_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        article_collection.find({**title: asd, body:asdd**}).toArray(function(error, results) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, results)
        });
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your form please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a couple of query string params with the url to /search.

For example:

```
 /search?title=asd&body=asdd;
```

And then use the req object to grab them and pass to your function:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    var title = req.query.title
       ,body = req.query.body;

    postdb.findByTitle(title, body, function(error, article) {
        res.render('search.jade',
        { locals: {
            title: article.title,
            articles:article
        }
        });
    });
});
```